# changing ImageView properties several times

Tags: android, view, rotation, imageview

Does anybody knows how to change imageView properties within the same function?

I´ve got this piece of code:

```
double angle = MyTrigonometry.angleTwoVectors(sP, eP);
            imgViewSelected.setPivotX(0);
            imgViewSelected.setPivotY(0);
            imgViewSelected.setRotation((int) angle);
switch (sCombination) {

        case "C1":
            if (mMeasure.getmDescription() == "VPI") {
                if (mMeasure.getmCoordenate().x > mPartner.getmCoordenate().x) {
                    pX = imgViewSelected.getLayoutParams().width / 2;
                    pY = imgViewSelected.getLayoutParams().height / 2;
                    angle = 180;
                    doRotation(imgViewSelected, pX, pY, angle);
                }
            } else {
                if (mMeasure.getmCoordenate().x > mPartner.getmCoordenate().x) {
                } else {
                    pX = imgViewSelected.getLayoutParams().width / 2;
                    pY = imgViewSelected.getLayoutParams().height / 2;
                    angle += 180;
                    doRotation(imgViewSelected, pX, pY, angle);
                }
            }
            break;
}
```

is it only listening to the last rotation instruction. how can I change thee properties so it listens to all the instructions within the same function?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set different pivot points during an Adapter `getView()` call, `View` will not refresh the view before the adapter is done with its child, therefore only after view is updated `setPivot()` will set its new properties.

Found a way around by just positioning to a desired point of the screen and rotating the `ImageView` only once per call.